# iPhone: What is the best way to use both OpenGL and the native user interface in an application?

Tags: iphone, opengl, user-interface

I'm pretty new to the iPhone platform, so I'm wondering what the best way to switch between OpenGL rendering and a UIView might be?

Any comments much appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

There's no need to switch modes at all.  OpenGL ES rendering on the iPhone is done in a CAEAGLLayer Core Animation layer.  This can be used as the base layer for a UIView, which means that you can combine all the UIView layout and touch handling with your 3-D rendering.  This UIView can be fullscreen or placed anywhere on the display.  UIViews also can be made subviews of your 3-D view, therefore they can appear above your rendering.

The OpenGL ES Application Xcode template gives you an OpenGL layer within a UIView instance and is a good place to start.  For a more complex example, I can direct you to the [source code for Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/02/molecules-source-code-now-available), my 3-D molecular viewer.  In that application, I use a lot of the view functionality for touch detection and place an info button in the lower right as a subview.  I even replace that view with another to produce a flip animation when going to the application's settings.