# Stacking UIViews with blend modes in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, calayer

I have two different `UIImageViews`. I'd like to make the top `UIImageView` blend in using the Screen blend mode with the bottom `UIImageView`.

I know of the property of `CALayer`: `compositingFilter` and I know that it doesn't work in iOS. I've searched a lot for solutions, and I've found how one should subclass `UIView` and override `drawRect`.

I've tried to set the context in `drawRect` to the screen blend mode, although it still draws every one of the images normally. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, or the approach should be different. Maybe I need OpenGL or CALayer to achieve this. Could someone assist?

Comment: Post your code. Also, you're going to have to draw both images in one view; you can't blend one view with the contents of another view.

Comment: @KurtRevis I know that I can draw two images in one UIView using screen, that is basic drawing in drawRect. I needed to do it between views. If it doesn't exist for now, post that as the answer, so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do a non-composite blend between UIViews on iOS. UIKit doesn't provide the functionality, and you've already noted, CALayer can't do it either.

In general, implementing -drawRect in a UIView won't help you. You're drawing into an empty bitmap -- it doesn't contain the bits of the views behind it, since those might change at any time (any view or layer might be animated). CA fundamentally assumes that layers' contents should be independent of each other.

You *could* try, in your `-drawRect:`

1. create an image context
2. capture the views under your view using `-[CALayer renderInContext:]` for each
3. create an image from the image context
4. draw that image into your view
5. set the blend mode and draw on top of that

But that will be slow and fragile, and won't work if you animate any of the views. I wouldn't recommend it.

If you really need to do this, you're going to have to switch your whole scene to render with OpenGL, [where you've got more freedom](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17043/blend-modes-in-cocos2d-with-glblendfunc).

Comment: Would there be some way to add an OpenGL view to the scene that would allow you to composite content over it? Or perhaps you could render offscreen, capture that as a texture, and then use OpenGL to draw your scene?

Comment: Offscreen rendering of UIViews would have to use `-[CALayer renderInContext:]` like I described. But yes, you could then draw that into your OpenGL context, then blend stuff over it. Same list of disadvantages.

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410350/mixing-opengl-and-uikit

Comment: What version of iOS is this answer relevant as of?