# Applying Blend Modes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, blending

What I'm trying to do is convert [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0W3N3B3L2N1w0z2O1J2u/Image%202015-07-06%20at%205.00.22%20AM.png) icon with solid white background into [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/311l2I3H202p1j1Y0127/Image%202015-07-06%20at%204.08.18%20AM.png) icon with blended background.

The background behind the icon is not really important, what I'm trying to achieve is the effect applied to the icon. The icon was created by using the `Soft Light` blend mode in Photoshop. I want to recreate that in iOS.

This is the code I've tried, inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14169247/5084415):

```
@IBOutlet weak var cogButton: UIButton!

func applyCogBackground() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cogButton.frame.size, false, 1)
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(cogButton.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    UIImage(named: "Cog")?.drawInRect(cogButton.bounds, blendMode: kCGBlendModeSoftLight, alpha: 1)
    var result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    cogButton.setBackgroundImage(result, forState: .Normal)

}
```

I'm using `drawHierarchyInRect()` instead of `CALayer.renderInContext()` because I've been told it is much faster performance wise. Regardless, either ways both end up with the same result. The icon is unaltered (it retains its solid white background). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying a different rendering mode for the button's image.

```
cogButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"Cog")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just results in [this](http://i.imgur.com/i2rEPFG.png) :( Thank you for trying though.