# Made a 2d game in opengl ES for iphone. Should i use uikit for the interface on top of it?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uikit, opengl-es

I made a very simple 2d game with OpenGl ES for Iphone (kind of tetris mixed with arkanoid stuff, for fun).
Now i need to build the UI below (playground is transparent) and on top of the play space.
Score, level and player display, background animation, control buttons... Should i (can i?) use Uikit for all these elements ?
Is openGL recommended ? if so, why ? performance wise ?

THX all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mix OpenglES with standard Cocoa widgets on an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057529/can-i-mix-opengles-with-standard-cocoa-widgets-on-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the link Brad Larson listed, I wanted to add that making a transparent openGL layer is easy, however it will cause a drag on performance. The amount depends on several factors, but for a simple game, having a transparent openGL layer shouldn't be a problem. However, with a large number of polygons I saw a performance hit.

Comment: I think this is something Allan Schaffer usually mentions at developer talks; a transparent OpenGL view on top of other views (or manipulated in a bunch of other ways, such as most rotations and other layer transforms) costs quite a lot, but other transparent views on top of OpenGL don't cost very much.

Comment: That is a good thing to point out! I suppose it is something I should benchmark, I just never got around to it.