# What is the exact performance cost when mixing Metal with UIKit?

Tags: ios, graphics, uikit, metal

This question closely relates to [What is the exact performance cost when mixing OpenGL with UIKit in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712043/what-is-the-exact-performance-cost-when-mixing-opengl-with-uikit-in-iphone) which covers this but for OpenGL.

I am essentially wondering what, if anything has changed with Metal now being more natively supported?

I am considering doing a full screen UIKit view above my full screen view to make my UI and Animations system easier but I don't want to incur a huge fee for doing so as the below metal layer is already rather intense on the processor and I want to support lower level hardware.

Some follow up questions:

1. If a UIKit element was covering half of the screen would the GPU still do the work to calculate the color of those pixels or would they be discarded in a deferred rendering sort of way.
2. Is it possible to mix my UIKit and Metal layers with additive blending?